# a realistic usage of composition in python

Tags: python, object-composition

i have been reading about composition in python and after following some articles and answers here on stackoverlow i think i am able to get ***what*** it is and ***how*** it is implemented. but one question to which i am unable to find answer is ***why*** composition? (not comparing with benefits over inheritance). here is an example that i got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861785/composition-and-aggregation-in-python):

```
class Salary:
    def __init__(self,pay):
        self.pay=pay

    def get_total(self):
       return (self.pay*12)

class Employee:
    def __init__(self,pay,bonus):
        self.pay=pay
        self.bonus=bonus
        self.obj_salary=Salary(self.pay)

    def annual_salary(self):
        return "Total: "  +  str(self.obj_salary.get_total()+self.bonus)


obj_emp=Employee(100,10)
print (obj_emp.annual_salary())
```

i would like to understand with a little realistic example where it would benefit by seperating two related classes( **and what benefits exactly?**)

Comment: `Salary` can be subclassed - *wage*, *tredicesima* etc. And an `Employee` type may *compose* any of the subclasses.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye can't i use `pay` directly as an `object attribute` of `Employee` class?

Comment: That limits you to a numeric value. With the `Salary` class, you can track other relevant attributes relating to employee compensation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using an extended version of your example

```
class Salary:
    def __init__(self,pay):
        self.pay=pay

    def get_total(self):
       return (self.pay*12)

    def increase(self):
        self.pay *= 1.1


class Employee:
    def __init__(self,pay,bonus):
        self.pay=pay
        self.bonus=bonus
        self.obj_salary=Salary(self.pay)

    def annual_salary(self):
        return "Total: "  +  str(self.obj_salary.get_total()+self.bonus)


obj_emp=Employee(100,10)
print (obj_emp.annual_salary())
```

calling employee.salary.increase makes much more sense than employee.increase

Also what if you needed multiple objects? would you inherit one of them or all of them leading to name possible name clashes?

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.screens       = [LoadingScreen, MapScreen]        
        self.player        = Player()
        self.display       = Display()
        self.stats         = Stats(self.display)
        self.screenIndex   = self.player.getScreen()
        self.currentScreen = self.screens[self.screenIndex]()
        self.run()
```

*** EDIT ***
after looking at this

```
but on looking it up again i find that increase could be renamed to increaseSalary so employee.increaseSalary() would make sense right?
```

you could simply move the increase to the employee class but what if you had a Manager class or a Boss class you would need to repeat the same code for each class

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self,pay,bonus):
        self.pay=pay
        self.bonus=bonus

    def annual_salary(self):
        return "Total: "  +  str(self.obj_salary.get_total()+self.bonus)

    def increase_salary(self):
        self.pay *= 1.1


class Manager:
    def __init__(self,pay,bonus):
        self.pay=pay
        self.bonus=bonus

    def annual_salary(self):
        return "Total: "  +  str(self.obj_salary.get_total()+self.bonus)

    def increase_salary(self):
        self.pay *= 1.1

class Boss:
    def __init__(self,pay,bonus):
        self.pay=pay
        self.bonus=bonus

    def annual_salary(self):
        return "Total: "  +  str(self.obj_salary.get_total()+self.bonus)

    def increase_salary(self):
        self.pay *= 1.1
```

***OR*** only once

```
class Salary:
    def __init__(self,pay):
        self.pay=pay

    def get_total(self):
       return (self.pay*12)

    def increase(self, addition):
        self.pay *= addition
```

you could also use a class methods to find average, max, min etc a lot easier

Comment: @JoshuaNixoxn thanks `employee.salary.increase` makes much more sense and also using multiple objects is an eye-opener for me :)

Comment: but on looking it up again i find that `increase` could be renamed to `increaseSalary` so `employee.increaseSalary()` would make sense right?

Comment: Sorry it's a little long but hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to figure out what should have responsibility for what and how you should manage things. People tend to distinguish composition and inheritance as "has a" and "is a". An employee has a salary, but an employee is not a salary. As such, an employee object would have a salary object. That salary object would handle all the things the deal with salary:

```
class Ledger:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = [];

    def add_pay(self, amount):
        self.items.append(amount)
        return self

    def total(self):
        return sum(self.items)

class Salary:
    def __init__(self,per_annum,periods):
        self.per_annum = per_annum
        self.periods = periods

    def get_pay(self):
        return self.per_annum / self.periods

class Employee:
    def __init__(self,salary):
        self.salary = salary
        self.ledger = Ledger()


salary = Salary(1200, 24)
employee = Employee( salary )
print( employee.salary.get_pay() )

employee.ledger.add_pay( employee.salary.get_pay() )
print(employee.ledger.total())

employee.ledger.add_pay( 37 )
print(employee.ledger.total())
```

Likewise, a salary has nothing to do with transactions. So an employee can have a ledger that keeps tracks of payments. This takes care of the bonus problem. A bonus is not salary, so salary shouldn't take responsibility for it. And, a bonus is not an employee, but an employee can have a ledger. Every time the employee gets money, just add it to the ledger.

But, this doesn't mean that you should use this example. It's just one demonstration of one object containing other objects that handle the work. You aren't trying to model how the real world works but figuring out what pieces your code needs to manage and how to effectively do that. This often means the various components that you need to use (database, whatever) sometimes decide how you best structure things.

Answer (score -1):

ok i'll give it a try even though i'm kind of a noob. also there may be some points i'm missing but this is the way i like to think about it, any who, the answer:

because it gives you a lot of agility and allows you to 'compose' objects together that may not necessarily have a parent/child relationship (what in classical OOP is referred to as a IS-A type inheritance)

for example say you have a `rifle`class. you want to add (or compose) `attachments` onto it.

how would you do this with inheritance? it wouldn't be very flexible.

so what you could do is define your attachments as there own classes, say a `sight` and a `muzzle break` class, and then declare instances of these attachment classes as fields in your `rifle` class and BAM you now have access to the methods defined in `sight` and `muzzle break`, just as when with inheritance a child class has access to its superclasses methods.

anyway to continue, you can see from this example how easy it would be to now create all sorts of weapon classes, like a `howitzer`, and if done properly you could declare instances of `sight` and `muzzle break` in `howitzer`.

notice that the relationship hierarchy we've created is completely flat.

to do all this with inheritance, you would define a base class, such as  `weapon` with the same methods defined in `sight` and `muzzle break`. you would then crate child classes that branch out to `rifle` and to `howitzer`.

now imagine you don't want `rifle` to have a `sight` but a `scope`. you have to go through all these hoops and shenanigans in your base class to achieve this.

well with composition you would simply just create a new class `scope` (which could actually inherit from `sight`), remove the instances of `sight` from `rifle` and insert a field instance of `scope`. note that no changes were made to `howitzer`.

with all that said i still think inheritance is a useful tool to be exploited in the proper situations, just like composition.